# Is there a way to remove everything before and including a tab (or space) for each line of a file using sed?

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file where I want to remove everything before and including the first space for each line. For example, if my file looks like this:

```
>JQ907469.1 Gracilariopsis mclachlanii voucher BG0072 23S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence; plastid
>JQ907467.1 Gracilariopsis longissima voucher BG0052 23S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence; plastid
>JQ907456.1 Hydropuntia rangiferina voucher BG0092 23S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence; plastid
>JQ907428.1 Gracilaria cornea voucher BG0112 23S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence; plastid
>JQ952662.1 Gracilariopsis tenuifrons voucher BG0042 23S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence; plastid
```

I want it to look like this

```
Gracilariopsis mclachlanii voucher BG0072 23S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence; plastid
Gracilariopsis longissima voucher BG0052 23S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence; plastid
Hydropuntia rangiferina voucher BG0092 23S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence; plastid
Gracilaria cornea voucher BG0112 23S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence; plastid
Gracilariopsis tenuifrons voucher BG0042 23S ribosomal RNA gene, partial sequence; plastid
```

I assume I can use sed to achieve my goal, but I'm not familiar enough with the notation and syntax of it yet to experiment. In the spirit of that, I'd love it if someone has a solution if they could explain why the code works the way it does.

Cheers

Comment: I would suggest you first read the sed manual and try to come up with a solution. Otherwise an answer to your question would need to explain a lot, and stack overflow is not meant to tutor people and is not a code writing service either.

Comment: One way could be to use the `s///` to match the first part and "substitute" with nothing. Good luck! :)

Comment: In general, please check out these guidelines when you ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Thanks for your help @petre , and I'll keep that in mind for the future

Answer (score 1):

Employing a regex, and assuming you're using a reasonably current GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/[^ \t]+[ \t]//' yourfile
```

If you're happy with how that looks, make that

```
sed -i -r 's/[^ \t]+[ \t]//' yourfile
```

How does it work? 
`s/` starts a **search & replace**

`^[^ \t]+[ \t]` is a regular expression that translates to **from the beginning of line match all non-space (or TAB) characters and the first space (or TAB)**

`//` the slashes, and the one above in the first part of the command, `s/`, are separators. The bit between the first two is the search pattern, the bit between the second two is the replacement (in your case, nothing).

`-r` tells GNU sed to use enhanced regular expression syntax.

`-i` tells it to modify the file in place.

Comment: Simplified `sed 's/^[^\s]*\s//'` or to ensure at least one non-whitespace `sed 's/^[^\s][^\s]*\s//'`. Using BRE ensures there is no issue with the OP's `sed`, some use `-E` some `-r`, for ERE, etc..

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and explanation @tink